# django aggregating values from related table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django to serve REST APIs to my front end app.

I have a SaleInvoice table and SaleLineItems table.

I created a SerializerMethodField (sub_total) to calculate a value based on values in fields of SaleLineItems table.

When I make a post/patch request to SaleLineItems, I am able to get the sub_total in response.data.

Now, **I need a grand_total** in SaleInvoice table/serializer which can aggregate all
sub_total values from SaleLineItems records which have the same Sale Invoice id.

If I do

```
SaleLineItems.objects.filter(sale_invoice=saleInvoiceId).aggregate(Sum('sub_total'))
```

I get an error telling me that I cannot use 'sub_total' but can use other regular fields of the SaleLineItems table.

Kindly help.

models.py

```
...

class SaleInvoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serial_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount_before_freight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    freight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    amount_after_freight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)




class SaleLineItems(models.Model):
    sale_invoice = models.ForeignKey(SaleInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product_qty = models.FloatField()
    product_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    product_disc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)


...
```

serializers.py

```
...

class SaleLineItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_sub_total(self, instance):
        return (
            Decimal(instance.product_qty)
            * Decimal(instance.product_rate)
            * Decimal(1-(instance.product_disc/100))
            ).quantize(Decimal("1.00"))

    sub_total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SaleLineItems
        fields = "__all__"
```

UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS:

```
class SaleInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_grand_total(self, saleInvoiceId):
        return SaleLineItems.objects.filter(sale_invoice=saleInvoiceId).aggregate(Sum('subTotal'))
    grand_total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SaleInvoice
        fields = "__all__"
```

Update2:

Removed `grand_total` from serializers.py

Added the below property in models.py for SaleInvoice model

Also added `related_name='items'` for SaleLineItems model

```
@property
def grandTotal(self):
    sum = 0
    for some in self.items.all():
        sum += some.sub_total
    return sum
```

This gets me the desired result but I have no clue if this is the right approach. So posted it here.

Comment: You're defining your `get_subtotal` at the serializer level, and Django ORM knows nothing about Django Rest Framework - define your field in the model to use in aggregate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After commenting out the code in serializers.py and adding the property as you suggested (and making migrations), I get this error: Cannot resolve keyword 'sub_total' into field. Choices are: id, product_disc, product_name, product_name_id, product_qty, product_rate, sale_invoice, sale_invoice_id. Also I don't see the sub_total field in http://127.0.0.1:8000/salelineitems/

Comment: Do not forget to restart Django and re-run all the migrations. If all the imports are in place, Django should discover updates in your model as a new `@property` has been added.

Comment: added a regular field, it did get detected but this one does not. Also, added the change in serializers.py fields as you suggested. No luck. I am googling for the reasons, if I dont' find a solution, I will try to remove migrations and start again.

Comment: Publish the error you're getting

Comment: I dont' get any errors when starting the server. If I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/salelineitems/, I dont' see the sub_total field, If I go to /saleinvoices/ I get the errorFieldError at /saleinvoices/
Cannot resolve keyword 'sub_total' into field. Choices are: id, product_disc, product_name, product_name_id, product_qty, product_rate, sale_invoice, sale_invoice_id

Comment: Make sure your viewset and your path/url is properly defined.

Comment: renamed sub_total to sub_crazy in all places, didn't work....subTotal works fine...didn't even run migrations for subTotal...Now, I can see subTotal field in /salelineitems/...now i still get the error which i got with /saleinvoices/...posted my code regarding that in the original question

Comment: Same thing - put your grand_total under `@property` in model and take it out of serializer - it does not belong there.

Comment: In the SaleInvoice model   @property
    def grandTotal(self):
       return SaleLineItems.objects.filter(sale_invoice=self.id).aggregate(Sum('product_rate'))

works but subTotal instead of product_rate does not work. Get the same error as before...cannot resolve keyword...

Comment: turns out I cannot use @property fields in aggregations...need to find other way out

Comment: Just create a property that will calculate it  and return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `SaleLineItems` model to be:

```
class SaleLineItems(models.Model):
    sale_invoice = models.ForeignKey(SaleInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product_qty = models.FloatField()
    product_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    product_disc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    @property
    def sub_total(self):
        return (
            Decimal(self.product_qty)
            * Decimal(self.product_rate)
            * Decimal(1-(self.product_disc/100))
            ).quantize(Decimal("1.00"))
```

The way you defined it will not allow Django know about your aggregated property, as it lives in serializer and Django models know nothing about Django Rest Framework serializers. 
The query is used at **Django** level (**Django ORM**), not **Django Rest Framework** level.

Then your serializer can be like:

```
class SaleLineItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SaleLineItems
        fields = ('id','sale_invoice','product_name','product_qty',
                  'product_rate', 'product_disc', 'sub_total',)
```

Notice the new field `sub_total` listed in the serializer.

In your `views.py` create a viewset:

```
class  SaleLineItemsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = SaleLineItems.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SaleLineItemsSerializer
```

In your urls.py add for Django 2.0 and later add:

```
    path('salelineitems/', SaleLineItemsList.as_view()),
```

For Django 1.7- 1.11 add:

```
    url(r'^salelineitems/',SaleLineItemsList.as_view()),
```